# Getting selected value from dropdown list in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockout, and have a problem getting a selected value from dropdown list. I tried to change value to '`selectedCity`' and I am getting `[Object object]`. Thanks!

**My HTML**

```html
<select data-bind="options: Cities, optionsText: 'CityNameRu', value: selectCity">
</select>

<span data-bind="text: selectedCity"></span>
```

**Knockout**

```
function CityModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    this.CityId = ko.observable(data.CityId);
    this.CityNameRu = ko.observable(data.CityNameRu);
    this.CityName = ko.observable(data.CityName);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Cities = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedCity = ko.observable();

    self.selectCity = function (city) {
        self.selectedCity(city.CityNameRu);
    };

    self.GetCities = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/FetchCities',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                self.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax(data);

            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
            }
        });
    };

    this.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax = function (models) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(models, function (model) {
            self.Cities.push(new CityModel(model));
        });
    };
```

**JSON response:**

```
[{"CityId":1,"CityName":"philadelphia","CityNameRu":"Филадельфия"},{"CityId":2,"CityName":"new-york","CityNameRu":"Нью Йорк"}
```

Comment: "I tried to change value to 'selectedCity' and I am getting [Object object]" where do you get this in the console? Which line of code is printing this message?

Comment: Here: <span data-bind="text: selectedCity"></span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the whole city object as value for `selectedCity`. You can also add a computed observable for retrieving text.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Cities = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedCity = ko.observable();

    self.selectCity = function (city) {
        self.selectedCity(city);
    };

    self.selectedCityNameRu = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var selectedCity = self.selectedCity();
        return selectedCity ? selectedCity.CityNameRu : '';
    }, self);
```

Then in your html bind to `selectedCityNameRu`

```
<span data-bind="text: selectedCityNameRu"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change a few things:

- No need for a `selectCity` function, just bind `value` straight to the observable.
- The `span text` is bound to an observable which holds a *reference to a city*, so the `text` will try to render that reference as well as it can by e.g. "Object object". Instead, execute the observable to get its value, and then choose which property to show as text.

  ```
  <span data-bind="text: !!selectedCity() ? selectedCity().CityNameRu : ''"></span>
  ```

Alternatively, you could utilize the `with` binding. Here's how:

```js
var data = [{"CityId":1,"CityName":"philadelphia","CityNameRu":"Филадельфия"},{"CityId":2,"CityName":"new-york","CityNameRu":"Нью Йорк"}];

var $ = { ajax: function(opts) { opts.success(data); } };

function CityModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  this.CityId = ko.observable(data.CityId);
  this.CityNameRu = ko.observable(data.CityNameRu);
  this.CityName = ko.observable(data.CityName);
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.Cities = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedCity = ko.observable();

  self.GetCities = function() {
    $.ajax({
      success: function(data) {
        self.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax(data);
      }
    });
  };

  self.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax = function(models) {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(models, function(model) {
      self.Cities.push(new CityModel(model));
    });
  };
  
  self.GetCities();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: Cities, optionsText: 'CityNameRu', value: selectedCity">
</select>

<div data-bind="with: selectedCity">
  <span data-bind="text: CityId"></span> -
  <span data-bind="text: CityName"></span> -
  <span data-bind="text: CityNameRu"></span>
</div>

<hr>

Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: 1st option works, but I am getting 'Unable to process binding "text: function (){return selectedCity().CityNameRu }"
Message: Cannot read property 'CityNameRu' of undefined' and page stops loading. Should I check if it is not empty something like    <!-- ko if: selectedCity().length > 0 -->
                    <span data-bind="text: selectedCity().CityNameRu"></span>
                    <!-- /ko if: -->?

Comment: Yes, you'd need a null check, I forgot. I've updated my answer with an approach similar to [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38195836/419956). If you *do* use the first approach (which I don't recommend, the `with` binding is clearer IMHO), I think @Michał's answer is more appropriate (cause it can be unit tested) and clean (cause your view stays more lean).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks, how to i set selected value? I'm trying `selectedCity({"CityId":1,"CityName":"philadelphia","CityNameRu":"Филадельфия"})` but it does not work

Comment: You have to select the exact right reference to the item in the list, you seem to be selecting a whole new inline object. - But I recommend creating a repo, and asking a new question, referencing this one. Comments aren't great for this kind of support. - Good luck!

Comment: @Jeroen I having a similar issue where I am trying to bind the field but getting error posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316106/unable-to-bind-the-field-within-the-foreach