# knockout get selected object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have list of items from observable array (grades) and there I hava select with some options from another observable array (courses). How can I get selected course when I click update button?
I can't change "value: course.id" with some observable value, becouse without it select won't fill with courses.

HTML:

```
<!-- ko foreach: grades -->
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="number" name="gradeValue" step=0.5 min=2.0 max=5.0 value=2.0
                                             title="Value" data-bind="value: value" placeholder="Value"></td>
                        <td><select name="id" required data-bind="options: $parent.courses,
                                                          optionsText: function(i) { return i.name(); },
                                                          optionsValue: function(i) { return i.id(); },
                                                          optionsCaption: 'Choose course',
                                                          value: course.id ">

                            </select></td>
                        <td><input type="date" data-bind="value: date" required></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Delete" data-bind="click: $root.deleteGrade.bind($data, $index())">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" data-bind="click: $root.updateGrade.bind($data, $index())"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- /ko -->
```

JS:

```
function ViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.courses = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.grades = ko.observableArray([]);
self.updateGrade = function (index) { //do something }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193457/getting-selected-value-from-dropdown-list-in-knockout-js

Comment: data-bind="value: selectedCourse " use
this.selectedCourse = ko.observable();

Comment: I can't change value. It need to stay value: course.id, because without that select won't be filled with courses

Comment: You may use JS or Jq to get value $("#idDrp").value

Comment: Don't know what you mean, Can you write it simpler? If you mean that I can get course id I already get, but I don't know how to gett course object from courses array,

Comment: if you are using jQuery add id to select option and you may get the value 
$("#idOfSelectList").value or document.getElementById("idOfSelectList").value